# How to figure out how to call a function in Python when you don't understand the argument types?

Tags: python-2.7

I am working with a large code base with a lot of python modules. I often am looking through the modules for functions that already exist so that I can use them for some purpose. In order to figure out how to call the functions, I have been opening the python interpreter, importing the modules, and attempting to call the function, and basically just guessing arguments to pass in to the function, and then print out what the function returns once something works out. For example, I have some function:
getProperties( propertyType, propertyName)

-- except I have no idea what are propertyType's, and what are propertyName's. Sometimes they're functions, objects, dictionaries, lists, or something else. Is there a way to check what propertyType or propertyName should be? How would you debug this in the general case? Can pdb help with this sort of thing?

Comment: That should all be documented. If it's not, you might need to dig a bit through each function  to see how the data is used, and that'll likely be painful.

Comment: have you tried `help(getProperties)`?

Comment: I have not, but just ran help(getProperties) and it crashed the interperter